# If $\cot(A-B)=3$ and $\cot(A+B)=2$, then evaluate $\tan A + \frac{1}{\cot^2A}+\tan^3A+\frac{1}{\cot^4A}+\cdots$

Tags: trigonometry

> Given:
>
> $$\cot (A-B) = 3 \qquad \cot (A+B) = 2$$
>
> Evaluate:
>
> $$\tan A + \frac{1}{\cot^2 A} + \tan^3 A + \frac{1}{\cot^4 A} + \cdots $$

Attempts:

I think that the given information is used to get the value of $A$ so I can input $A$ to the problems and using the formula of infinite sum of geometric sequence. I haven't touched that step yet. I am still trying to get the value of $A$.

From
$$\cot (A-B) = \frac{\cot A \cot B-1}{\cot A + \cot B}$$
I get to $\cot A - 5\cot B = 2$.

Now, I am stuck. Where should I do next?

Comment: Sorry, what is it we're trying to prove? You seem to have written an expression, not a claim. It's also unclear how that expression continues. If the fourth term had been $\frac{1}{\cot^4A}$, I'd guess it was a geometric series.

Comment: I meant solve. Yes. I think it is geometric sequence to solve

Comment: Oh, you mean *evaluate*. OK, but it's unclear what the $n$th term is. All we know is the first few terms are specific powers of $\tan A$.

Comment: Your second inverse square $\cot$ term has the same power as the first. Inferring the sequence from this implies you have an infinite sum of reciprocal squares of $\cot$, which would be infinite. Did you mean the second term to be to the power 4, not 2?

Comment: Oh. Yes. Power 4.

Comment: One more thing to double-check: are you saying one cotangent is $3$ while the other is $2$, or the first cotangent is $3$ times the other, thereby equalling $2$?

Comment: Um.. i changed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\tan{A}=x$ and $\tan{B}=y$.

Thus, we obtain the following system.
$$\frac{x-y}{1+xy}=\frac{1}{3}$$ and
$$\frac{x+y}{1-xy}=\frac{1}{2}$$ or
$$3(x-y)=1+xy$$ and
$$2(x+y)=1-xy,$$ which gives
$$5x-y=2$$ or $$y=5x-2.$$
Now, since $$2(x+y)=1-xy,$$ we obtain:
$$2(x+5x-2)=1-x(5x-2)$$ or
$$12x-4=1-5x^2+2x$$ or
$$5x^2+10x-5$$ or
$$x^2+2x-1=0.$$
Can you end it now?

Actually.

For $\tan{A}=-1-\sqrt2$ your series diverges.

Comment: $x^2 + 2x -1$ how?

Comment: @Lifeforbetter Your question, how I got this or how to solve this?

Comment: How i got this?

Comment: @Lifeforbetter I added something. See now.

Comment: Thanks. Is the answer $\frac{-1 +\sqrt2}{2-\sqrt2}$

Comment: Exectly! We can write it easier, but you are right

Comment: By mutiple it to 2 + $\sqrt2$ ?

Comment: @Lifeforbetter  Yes, it's better.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

There must be something wrong in the question

$\tan2A=\tan(A+B+A-B)=\cdots=1$

$1=\dfrac{2\tan A}{1-\tan^2A}$

One of the roots if $a=\sqrt2-1,|a|=\dfrac1{\sqrt2+1}<1$

The other root is $b=-\dfrac1a$

$|b|=\dfrac1{|a|}>1$

If $\tan A=p$

$$\sum_{m=0}^\infty p^{2m+1}=\dfrac p{1-p^2}$$ provided $p^2<1$

$$\sum_{n=0}\dfrac1{p^{2n}}=\dfrac{1/p^2}{1-1/p^2}$$ provided $\dfrac1{p^2}<1\iff p^2>1$

So, both infinite series cannot converge simultaneously

Comment: Why it get tan2A = 1?

Comment: @Lifeforbetter, $$\tan(A+B+A-B)=\dfrac{\tan(A+B)+\tan(A-B)}{1-\tan(A+B)\tan(A-B)}$$

Comment: Ok. I have no idea what you answer.. sorry. I am not on that level yet